# Find the value of 'K' .

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Let $\alpha , \beta \in R$ such that $2(\alpha-1)^3+3(\alpha-1)^2+6\alpha=0$ and $2(1-\beta)^3+3(1-\beta)^2-6\beta+12=0 $ and $\alpha \neq \beta$ , also graph of $y=f(x)$ is symmetric about the point $(1,0)$ . If $\int_\alpha^\beta f(x)dx=K(\alpha+\beta)$ , then find the value of $K$.

I tried approaching the problem by replacing $\alpha$ with $-\beta$ and vice versa but couldn't arrive at a meaningful solution , some help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.